# How to confirm Oracle CREATE DIRECTORY completed successfully?

Tags: oracle11g

Once I issue the command `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY foobar AS '/path/to/foobar/';`

How can I confirm the directory object exists?

Does it create an entry in any system table I can check?

I'm using this Oracle [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5007.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to list all the directory objects

```
select * from all_objects  where object_type = 'DIRECTORY'
```

it should be in that list if it is successful.

Comment: This table has a column called `OWNER`. Is the 'OWNER' the same as the 'USER' who issued the command?

Comment: @zundarz. Yes, OWNER is the user who created it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can query `all_directories`: